# MySQL Table Import always missing 1 row

Tags: mysql

Every week I import a table of our clients into MySQL and every week a random client is missing from that list. That same client might have been imported without problems the week before and then next week again imported perfectly fine, however MySQL will always omit one client from the import which makes my job very frustrating in trying to find who it was and manually fix it.

Has anyone run into similar issues in the past or have any idea why they might be happening?

I am using the MySQL table import wizard. Normally I don't have issues, but this specific client table export I get from another platform is having this issue every single week.

Comment: are you importing to excel?

Comment: I export client information from our platform into a csv, then I load the CSV into MySQL. The CSV has 10,000 rows but only 9,999 records are imported. Usually it's a random row from anywhere in the table, not just the last line.

Comment: *then I load the CSV into MySQL* Show complete destination table DDL and precise SQL statement. *I am using the MySQL table import wizard.* There is no such SQL statement. BE more precise - what client software do you use?

Comment: User14461410 please answer Akinas question as my answer is canonical only to excel so it would required to be removed if it does not fit your software and thus i need to know imminently

Comment: Like I said before I use the MySQL Data Table Import Wizard which definitely does exist. Export data from platform into a CSV file, import file into MySQL using the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting to *excel* using the Export wizard, it creates a sheet with the name of the table, but also creates a named range with the same name. The named range then contains only the region with data. Then when you add new data, this named region is not extended. And when you are later importing the data, you probably chose the name without the $ character on end. The name without the $ in the name represents the named region, which probably doesn't contain your newly inserted data. To load all the date chose the name with $ character or extent the named region to cover all the data in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the import from the Excel into a TEMPORARY (ie: not the final table), but one of the same structure.  Then, once that is done and the import of all names and columns are parsed, you can left-join from LIVE table to the TEMP table where the entry exists on LIVE but not in TEMP.  This would help find the missing import.  THEN, since the data is already in a valid table structure, you can pull in all new values from the temp table to the production, including adding any new that did not yet exist.